# overlay on html wont show in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, fullscreen

I have tried several things with no success. 
I have a video on top of which i have a div that serves as an overlay, on click the video will play. 
everything works normally but when in fullscreen, the overlay wont be display, no matter what the css is.
This only happens in chrome and in safari.

this is what i have.

```
    <div class="video_display" >
    <div id="play-pause-overlay" style="display: block;">
        <div class="play-overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <video webkit-playsinline="true" allowfullscreen="true" class="sm_video">
        <source src="http://assets/video/bbb_trailer_1080p.mp4?ts=961">
    </video>
    <div id="video-controls" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2147483647; opacity: 0.9; border-radius: 5px;">
        <div id="rewind" class="control_button">
            <div class="rewindIcon"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="play-pause" class="control_button_play">
            <div class="playIcon"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="SeekBar">
            <div class="seek-bar-container">
                <div id="seek-bar" class="bar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Duration">
            <div class="duration">00:00/00:00</div>
        </div>
        <div id="Mute" class="control_button">
            <div class="muteIcon"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="volume-container" class="volumeDiv">
            <input id="volume-bar" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
        </div>
        <div id="Full" class="control_button" style="display: inline-block;">
            <div class="fullIcon"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

file with css:

```
.play-overlay { position: relative;
 z-index: 100000000;
 opacity: 0.6;
}

#play-pause-overlay{ 
  cursor: pointer; 
  width: 100%; 
  position: absolute; 
  height: 100%; 
  background: url('//PlayIconOverlay.png') no-repeat center;
  z-index: 100000; 
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you ever find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Any element with width/height set to 100% will only be as large as its parent. I'd try to add this to your css:

```
html, body, .video_display {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```